# Yii: CJuiDatePicker field value not being set to null using JS

Tags: jquery, yii

I am using CJuiDatePicker input field for date value. After the user input, I need to set it to blank. I have used all of the following options in my JS routine but nothing seems to work. Its strange that I can select the value from date field but not set it to blank. I can not hide it since the date field is required for subsequent inputs.

```
$('#dateFieldId').val('');
$('#dateFieldId').val("");
$('#dateFieldId').val(null);
$('#dateFieldId').val()=null;
```

Following is my code snippet for generating the CJuiDatePicker:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
'model'=>$model,
'attribute'=>'history_date',
'options'=>array('changeMonth'=>'true','changeYear'=>'true','yearRange'=>'-70:+0'),             
));
```

Any tips....?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Faisal

Comment: So you can alert the value of the input after change but not set in to ""?

Comment: yes, i can alert the value that had been entered by the user but not reset it.

Comment: Can you post your JS used to handle that

Comment: Following is the JS code snippet:

    <script type="text/javascript">
function selectData(){
 var history_date=$('#dateFieldId').val();
alter(history_date);
}
</script>

Comment: Try set $model->history_date = null; before call widget

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why this wouldn't work?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#dateFieldId").change(function(){
            $(this).val("");
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is possible that the date selection on the graphical date picker is being set after you are clearing the input.

Alternatively, the datepicker API has a call back function. [Check out the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), there should be an after_select or call back function available

Comment: yes its strange. By the way, what you suggested would not let the user even enter the data, date is set to null soon as the user leaves the date field........ :(

Comment: Do you have an example online somewhere, or could you pop it in jsfiddle

Comment: no its not online yet, but the jsFiddle is also new to me, let me brush up myself there and get back....thanks a lot for your prompt replies....regards...

Comment: Cool sorry couldn' help, check out the documentation. It must be the setting of the date from the datepicker is being fired after any other js is executed

Comment: Well, now its working. I was adding a div in DOM and moved the date code before the addition of new div just to check if it is causing any error because then the processing would stop. To my surprise it worked...any thoughts on this....fundamentally, it should have worked otherwise....

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you were dynamically adding the element.  jQuery event handlers (e.g. `.change()`) won't attach to dynamically added events.

You need to use [on() and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Pick a permanent element on the page - `$('body')` should generally work, but performance wise, it's best to pick something further down, maybe the wrapper around your form?

For your input items, you'll need something like:

```
$('<parentSelector>').on('change', '#calendarSelector', function() { 
    $(this).val() = '';
})
```

Where the parentSelector is something higher in the DOM than the input element, and an element that exists at page load, maybe the form ID or something.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem here was to reset the existing items in the Body that I wanted to reset to NULL after the user has pressed the Add button. On the Add action, I take the value for dataField and dynamically creates a new item and add it to Body.  In reference to my last comments to Eskimo's answer, I am still confused why it would not reset dataField if I make it before the addition of dynamic content and only does it if I add it afterwards, any thoughts on that? What you pointed out will surely help me  whenever I am handling events with dynamic content. Regards, Faisal

Comment: @FaisalKhan From the sounds of your comment, it sounded as if the `#dateFieldId` was in the DOM you were adding, and if so, it's a new element that won't have a handler.  If I'm incorrect, about the date field being added dynamically (e.g. after the main page is loaded, i.e. via a javascript function), then this wouldn't apply.